# How to extract the value of an xml attribute?

Tags: xml, xpath

How can I extract the value autolex from this xml with xpath? Currently I am trying it with this xpath expression `/Context[@path]` but it returns the complete element.

I need only the value autolex

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- neue Version des context.xml zum Deployment ausserhalb des Tomcat webapps-verzeichnis -->
<Context path="/autolex" 
         docBase="../../../applications/srs-autolex-1.1.1-0.war" 
         clearReferencesStatic="true" 
         unpackWAR="false" 
         reloadable="false">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
    fileDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
    pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot;"
    prefix="autolex."
    suffix=".log"/>
  <ResourceLink global="pendb"
      name="jdbc/DataSource"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the attribute:

```
/Context/@path
```

Your original query, `/Context[@path]` selects `Context` elements with a `path` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This should work: `/Context/@path`